# Inserting into a string c++

Tags: c++, string, insert, stdstring

If i want to  insert the same character in a string  a number of times that the user enters 
For example:

```
int n=30;
string s="";
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    s=s+"M";
}
```

is there a more efficient way to make the same process in less time?    because if n is a big number  it will take the program quite long time to run

Answer (score 4):

According : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/
Case n°5 : Filling a string

```
str.append (14, 'd');
```

Will append 14 times the character 'd' in your string

Comment: i was just about to write the same thing. kudos :)

Comment: This is still linear in count though.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's faster, but it's surely of a better style:

```
s += std::string('M', n);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a more likely no, there isn't a more efficient way of doing it. Most operations will actually be linear in count. Including constructing an alternative string, appending to it using `std::string::append` and even `std::fill`. A good way to maybe get a speed up though is by using `s.push_back('M')` and by possibly making a reserve call but even then it won't be noticeably faster, if at all.